# how to write web services using cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Is it possible to write web services in CakePHP? any sample tutorial?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with webservice. What kind of webservice?

Answer (score 2):

Webservices are not really different from normal web applications. The main difference is the output.

Because you don't tell what kind of service you want to build, I only can give general advice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just format the output as XML or JSON or something else instead of HTML.